# Split large files by size limit without cutting lines

Tags: python, bash, split

So I am interested in splitting rather large files into 5Gig intervals. My goal is to have ALL partitions less than 5Gigs and the least ammount of partitions as possible.

While I WOULD normally use the split with a size limit, I need to ensure that lines remain intact (Which I cannot get split by size to do).

I have been contemplating using the file size and line count to determine the number of lines I could split per file

e.g.

```
File size = 11Gig
File line count = 900
File limit = 5Gig
ceiling(11/5) = 3
900/3 = 300
#Split the file by line limiting 300 each.
```

While this would probably usually work, due to the nature of line elements file sizes COULD still be above 5gigs if there is one extremely large line in a segment of the file.

I'm contemplating using python (It handles numbers much better and seems less hackish), but then I would loose bashes file manipulation speed.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a better alternative in bash?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: 900 lines is nothing, you can just loop over it. I'd loop over each line, keep a counter for the bytes written to the current file. If it, with the current line, goes above 5G, start a new file. If the line itself is over 5G, throw an error. (If you have to save memory, this will get somewhat more complicated, but still possible.)

Comment: Linux split has a --lines=NUMBER option to split by NUMBER of lines per output file.

Comment: The numbers above are not an accurate scale to what I will actually be doing, they are just given to provide an easy to understand example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the split man-page:

```
...
-C, --line-bytes=SIZE
put at most SIZE bytes of lines per output file
...
```

The description of this option may not be very obvious, but it seems to cover what you are asking for: the file is split at the latest possible line break before reaching SIZE bytes.

Comment: Actually that does look like it will solve my issue. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Unfortunately, this may cut lines, namely when they are larger than `SIZE`. I'd be interested in a solution that keeps lines intact no matter what...